# Create a folder for all the shortcuts

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, .desktop, shortcuts, gnome-shell-extension

My job has a certain standardization for Desktops in Windows, however we've decided to chance some of our O.S.s to Ubuntu. Herein lies the problem, in order to make the transition "as smooth as possible" my boss wants to have a folder that contais all the shortcuts for the programs we use, and this folder to be located in the Desktop.

All I know is how to create a shortcut on the Desktop by creating the .desktop file. However it seems the shortcut stops working when I move it to the new folder, is this a bug, and if not, how could I creat a folder with all the shortcuts the users might need?

Edit: The .desktop files will point to the preogram folder, more specifically to the equivalent of the .exe file, so the person using it just gotta click it twice and open the program.
The .desktop file would be moved to a folder in the Desktop, which would be a folder with all the shortcuts for each programs. (To illustrate, image creating a folden in a Windows desktop, and then moving all the shortcuts from programs like Office, Video Player, Text Editor, IDEs. We're trying to replicate this in Ubuntu).

Comment: To help us answer this: Where are the .desktop files pointing to? If it is relative to the Desktop, and moved it may break. Where are the .desktop files being moved to? Is it is a folder on the Desktop or another folder elsewhere? I recommend editing your question to answer these questions, be as specific as you can, then we can more easily help.

Comment: It might be a permissions issue. You can `chmod 755` the `.desktop` files and see if that solves the problem. This will allow anyone to read and execute the file with only the owner having write permission

Comment: @Nmath I don't really have a problem whenever the file is on the desktop, however when we tried to move those files(with permissions and all) to a folder created on the Desktop it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Or does chmod 755 add the permission to run .desktop files outside of the Desktop? 'cause I've been using the chmod+x for the .desktop file to work and all that

Comment: chmod 755 means that the owner can read, write, and execute and everyone else can read and execute. chmod +x adds the execute permission to everyone, but it doesn't necessarily make the file readable